# How to construct time.Time with timezone offset

Tags: go, time, timezone, timezone-offset

This is an example date from an Apache log:

```
[07/Mar/2004:16:47:46 -0800]
```

I have successfully parsed this into year(int), month(time.Month), day(int), hour(int), minute(int), second(int), and timezone(string).

How can I construct time.Time such that it includes the `-0800` time zone offset?

This is what I have so far:

```
var nativeDate time.Time
nativeDate = time.Date(year, time.Month(month), day, hour, minute, second, 0, ????)
```

What should I use in place of `????`? `time.Local` or `time.UTC` is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`time.FixedZone()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#FixedZone) to construct a [`time.Location`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Location) with a fixed offset.

Example:

```
loc := time.FixedZone("myzone", -8*3600)
nativeDate := time.Date(2019, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, loc)
fmt.Println(nativeDate)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IbMPYUNryBe)):

```
2019-02-06 00:00:00 -0800 myzone
```

If you have the zone offset as a string, you may use [`time.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) to parse it. Use a layout string that only contains the reference zone offset:

```
t, err := time.Parse("-0700", "-0800")
fmt.Println(t, err)
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Q8zQsNN8Cpq)):

```
0000-01-01 00:00:00 -0800 -0800 <nil>
```

As you can see, the result [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) has a zone offset of -0800 hours.

So our original example can also be written as:

```
t, err := time.Parse("-0700", "-0800")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

nativeDate := time.Date(2019, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, t.Location())
fmt.Println(nativeDate)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lQqTwN2GR0L)):

```
2019-02-06 00:00:00 -0800 -0800
```

Comment: What's a good way to convert `-0800` to `-8*3600`?

Comment: So the `-0700` is arbitrary as it is just a formatting specifier? Could this be any valid time zone?

Comment: @jftuga The layout (format) must be given using the reference time, which is `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006`. So the zone offset in the layout must be -7 hours, formatted in a way it is in your input. This is detailed in [`time.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse).